# Need multiple Twilio numbers to forward to single number in emergency only

Tags: twilio

My users all have accounts with unique Twilio numbers that feed them into my app. If my app goes down, can I have an emergency protocol where I effectively "flip a switch" and have every Twilio number forward to a single number?

Example:
Accounts A, B, and C have unique Twilio numbers. When a customer calls A, A's office number is forwarded to the unique Twilio number, where our app collects the data A requires; and similarly for B & C.
If our app goes down, I want my customer service line to get all the calls from A, B, and C. Is it possible to create an emergency protocol such that all those numbers get forwarded to my customer service line? I need to be able to do it basically instantly so there is no down-time.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking out Fallback URL's:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security/availability-reliability

You can configure every phone number with a fallback URL that Twilio will request of the HTTP request to the Voice Request URL fails.  You could set this URL to something like a failover data center running a backup of your application, or even to something as simple as a static XML file that return some fallback TwiML.

Hope that helps.